# How to Set BackgroundImage for Button in WindowsFormsHost?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background, windowsformshost

How can I set background image on button in `WindowsFormsHost`?

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfbutton1" Width="200" Height="100" Background="White" Visibility="Visible" >
    <wf:Button Height="23" Left="145" Top="127" wf:Name="button1" Width="75" 
               Click="button1_Click" Visible="True" FlatStyle="Flat"
               BackgroundImage="C:\\Users\\Kvint\\Desktop\\Background.bmp" />
</WindowsFormsHost >
```

Comment: I can not link to image
<wf:Button Name="button1" BackgroundImage = "С:\\Background.bmp"/>
not working

BackgroundImage ="/WpfApplication4;component/Images/Background.bmp"
not working too

Comment: i am use WinForms button by dint of WindowsFormsHost, WinForms button have property BackgroundImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your button a name like any other WPF element:

```
<WindowsFormsHost ... >
    <wf:Button x:Name="button1" ... />
</WindowsFormsHost >
```

Then reference that in the code-behind:

```
button1.BackgroundImage
    = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Kvint\Desktop\Background.bmp");
```

If you're looking for a purely XAML approach, I'll leave that to someone else. I'm not sure it's even possible in this case.

Comment: no i am not looking for a purely XAML approach
button1.BackgroundImage
    = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Kvint\Desktop\Background.bmp"); not working. No error and no image